# Python Function to configure com port

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, serial-port

I have written some basic python code to allow connection over com port. I would like to create a function to pass any com port into the function.

I have written some basic python code to allow connection over com port. I would like to create a function to pass any com port into the function.

Original code

```
#Import Serial
import serial

#Import Time
import time

# Set COM Port.....
ser = serial.Serial('COM12', 115200, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, rtscts=0)
```

---

Attempted function code

```
def my_function(port):
  # Import Serial
    import serial

  # Import Time
    import time

  # Set COM Port.....
    ser = serial.Serial('COM + "port"', 115200, timeout=0, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, rtscts=0)

myfunction(COM12)
```

Comment: Not _exactly_ sure what your question is. But `'COM + "port"'` is an issue. `"port"` here is just a string, so it doesn't actually use your function input. Something like this could work: `'COM' + port`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass 'COM12' as a string to the function ie. with quotation marks:

```
import serial
import time

def my_function(port):

  # Set COM Port.....
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 115200, timeout=0, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, rtscts=0)

my_function('COM12')
```

When you pass `'COM12'` to the function, it's essentially setting `port = 'COM12'` inside the function.

Comment: Super job! Works well now. Thanks for the help